# Denied boarding on second leg of trip: compensation

Tags: air-travel

It was a trip from New York to Glasgow via London Heathrow on one 1 ticket from BA. New York to London arrived on time for the Glasgow flight. We were denied boarding for the second leg and BA offered 250 compensation for denied boarding regulation (admitted overbooking although we were checking in and bumped off) only within the UK, as it was not a delay but denied boarding and flight did go without us... Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: First things first:  don't sign anything until a thorough answer is given here.  Airlines occasionally try to lowball you on the compensation, and since the UK is (checks watch) still in the EU, the generous EU rules on compensation for denied boarding probably apply.

Comment: Thank you Michael...they have finally offered the 250 after months of contact....I just wondered about the one ticket from JFK to GLA as we paid to travel from one to the other within a given time so final destination was over 7 hours late ....

Comment: 250 what? GBP, EUR, USD?

Comment: EUR Peter....happy with that....it was one ticket from JFK to GLA so final destination delay of 1 ticket was over 7hours

Answer (score 8):

A flight from LHR–GLA is within the EU and covers a distance of about 550 km.  A passenger who is "bumped" from such a flight is due compensation, rebooking/reimbursement, and "assistance" under [FCR 26/2004.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_Compensation_Regulation_261/2004)  According to these regulations, a passenger denied boarding for a flight of this distance is entitled to:

- EUR 250 cash compensation (half this amount if the passenger is offered an alternate flight that arrives within two hours of the original flight), **and**
- Your choice between reimbursement of your flight (and return to your point of origin);  re-routing to your destination at the earliest possible time;  or re-routing to your destination at a later time, subject to seat availability, **and**
- "Assistance", consisting of:

  - Refreshments
  - Food
  - Accommodation (if you are rebooked to travel the next day)
  - Transport to your accommodation and return to the airport
  - 2 telephone calls, telex, fax messages or emails

You can find more information about the EU regulations on the EU's website:  [Air passenger rights](https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/travel/passenger-rights/air/index_en.htm).

Comment: Be sure to demand your right to send 2 telex messages, because when else are you going to get that? :)

Comment: @ZachLipton: But where should he send those?

Comment: He should demand they are sent to the person expecting him at his destination, and not accept excuses like 'but they don't have a Telex machine'.

Comment: Airlines still use IATA teletype messages, so I guess you could demand to send messages to the airline complaining about bumping you.